# Cannot find default value in sysctl - Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, sysctl

Im running Ubuntu 14.0.4 LTS and im trying to change some default values to optimize.

I run **sysctl -a** to see all values.

I have **/etc/sysctl.conf** and **/etc/sysctl.d/** which has a few 10-*.conf files in it.

I want to change **net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog** value but it is not present in any of the configuration files above.

a) Shall I just enter the new value in any of those files? Where is the default value stored?

b) After changing the value shall I run **service procps start** or **sysctl -p**?

I have read that the configuration files can be in the following places:

1. /run/sysctl.d/*.conf (not present on my system)
2. /usr/local/lib/sysctl.d/*.conf (not present on my system)
3. /usr/lib/sysctl.d/*.conf (not present on my system)
4. /lib/sysctl.d/*.conf (not present on my system)
5. /etc/sysctl.d/*.conf
6. /etc/sysctl.conf

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The default value for kernel runtime parameters is selected/set at compilation time of the kernel (module). `sysctl` is used to read those parameters and allows you to modify/override those parameters at both system boot and at runtime.

Personally I have never used any other file than `/etc/sysctl.conf` and I would use `sysctl -p` to verify the syntax of the new parameters I set.
(Except when I don't use `sysctl` at all and manipulate kernel paramaters directly e.g. with the traditional `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` )

Comment: I prefer making a new file under `sysctl.d`. That way possible OS updates on the `sysctl.conf` file won't overwrite my changes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I see, so if the default is 256 and I set it to 5000, then in order to "go back" to default I will have to set it to the value it originally was, removing the new value wont restore the default value. However isn't directly writing to "/proc/sys/..." temporary? Or will it survive reboot? Thanks in advance